# Can I set IP restrictions using the Wix IIS extension?

Tags: iis, wix, wix3, wix-extension

Is it possible to set-up IP address restrictions for an IIS site through a Wix installer? I don't see it mentioned in the IIS extension documentation. I want the site to be available to only one specific IP address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, not today. It'd be great if you contributed the code to handle that case to the WiX community though.